# iPhone Target Certain Devices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm want to target the iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, iPod Touch (4th generation).  I do not want to target the iPhone 3G and iPhone 3GS.  I've seen some post that said this is not possible.  However, I notice in the App Store that some apps do this such as the picture below.

How would I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: have you tried googling it? there is lots of information about this out there

Comment: @JustinMeiners thank you that is truly great advice, I must consider that next time

Comment: It is, here is just a few related questions I found in 3 minutes http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/59339-require-iphone4-only-my-application.html  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdkhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897680/best-way-to-support-functionality-for-previous-ios-versions-and-deprecated-metho/9898000#9898000

Comment: @JustinMeiners well one link does not work, and the other two did not answer my question which is why I created this post. Don't worry, my question was answered though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those requirements show up because the developers have put `armv7` as an entry in the [`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) `Info.plist` key.  There's no key specifically to target the iPhone 4 and up, although you can probably eliminate the 3GS using one of the other keys.

Why are you trying to stop people from installing your app on older devices?

Comment: Yes, my scrollview and picker won't work properly on the iPhone 3G/3GS, I immediately though armv7 but the iPhone 3GS is armv7

Comment: Is this an app that is already on the App Store?  Apple don't let you add restrictions to existing apps.  Why don't the things you mention work on those models?  Surely it's better to just fix that instead?

Comment: It's currently in the App Store, but i'm about to make an update that app.  I just happened to come across this error after actually testing my app on the 3G/GS.  The OS version doesn't matter, just seems to be those devices.

Comment: The UIScrollView and UIPicker won't work properly, and the only way to fix it is to disable the scroll from within the picker.  Since the picker takes up most of the scroll view, its very difficult to scroll.  Strangest error i've come across yet

Comment: I'm just going to mismatch keys until I get the desired results, thanks

Comment: As I said before, Apple don't let you add restrictions to existing apps.  If you use this, you'll have to delete your existing app from the App Store and upload it as a brand new app.  Your existing users won't be prompted to upgrade, if it's a paid app, they'll have to pay again, and you'll lose your chart positions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to set [`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) to specify exactly which features your app needs. For example, the `camera-flash` key is only going to be true for iPhone4 and later, if that's what you need.

There's also a [Q&A article](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1397/_index.html) on it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the features the device needs with UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities, you can also specify the minimum iOS version that needs to be installed.

See this [Apple Technical Note, TN2250](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html).

Comment: Yes but since the 3GS can get update 5.1, that doesn't solve the issue

Comment: I can safely eliminate the 3G with armv7, but the 3GS is the issue

Comment: Right, setting the iOS version is just one piece of the puzzle. What iOS version is on the 3GS device you are testing with?

Comment: Since the iPhone 3GS can get update iOS 5.1, that makes that flag irrelevant

Comment: What I'm trying to get at, is maybe the problem you're having with  UIScrollView and UIPicker are to do with the iOS version you're testing with.